# Asynchronous transactions in Room

Tags: android, android-room

Let's say I have the following database transactions on a thread(not main)

```
query  //asynchronous 
insertions  //synchronous 
insertions  //synchronous
```

From what I've searched queries are asynchronous and if executed sequentially with other synchronous transactions they causing problems or even parallel insertion from different threads. How can I control which procedure executes first?

Comment: queries are asynchronous? so is there any callback giving you the returned data? no

Comment: Indeed.But what about parallel insertions (synchronous ) from different threads?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to try using Room with RxJava. [Read more](https://medium.com/google-developers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

By using Maybe, Single or Flowable, you can execute your queries asynchronously, and you can setup a callback to be executed when it is complete (or when it's failed).

And to make sure your data operations queries are running well in proper order in one transaction, just make another function with `@Transaction` in your `@Dao` class. [Read more](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Transaction)

Comment: But what about parallel insertions (synchronous ) from different threads?

Comment: Can you give me an example on how that might happen? I mean, do you want to execute them in another Thread like in AsyncTask?

Comment: Yeah lets say i have 2 insertions ni two different threads running together. How the database will handle this situation? Will one of the threads pause until the other finish, or they will have access simultaneously? Does the method runInTransaction help ?

Comment: Android uses SQLite 3.x and unless a thread cannot access or connect to the database, your 2 insertions will be executed simultaneously, without knowing the proper order.

If you really want to make sure in a proper order and/or you need to rollback if one fail, you need to put those queries in Transaction.

Comment: So Transaction provides a safe way to not execute queries simultaneously right?

Comment: Yes. Using Transaction in your situation is much better approach, I think.